# debugging zk project in eclipse return "Source not found." Error

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am new in zk.
I create a new .zul file.
when I am navigate to my new page in Browser, "Source not found." error appear in eclipse in debug mode, while running application works correct.
I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0 and eclipse Juno with zk studio plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in zul file.  tag should be encompassed with  tag!